# How oin blade form show old value?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 8/ bootstrap 4 / laravelcollective/html 6.2 app
I use old in form field definition :

```
{!! Form::text(
    'name',
    !empty(old('name'))? Purifier::clean(old('name')): $user->name,
    ['placeholder' => 'Name','class' => 'form-control editable_field', 'autocomplete'=>'of']
) !!}
@error('name')
    <p class="validation_error" role="alert">{{ $message }}</p>
@enderror
```

as it works ok, expect cases when from database value was read but cleared by operator:

```
then old value is visible.
```

I tried this way

```
isset(old('name'))? Purifier::clean(old('name')): $user->name,
```

But got error:

```
Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)
```

Can you advice proper way ?

Thanks!

Comment: normally you would do something like `old('field', $user->field)` if you weren't using form model binding ... you probably don't need to purify something you are putting in the form since you will be purifying it when it gets submitted

Comment: Where can I check  that data are purified  on submitting without using mews/purifier in form ?

Comment: you use it when you process the form submission ... but if you wanted to adjust the user's old input that you give back to them to purify it, you can ... you will be purifying it after the form is submitted anyway